# how to add attribute of the clicked element to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

is there any way to add an attribute of the clicked element to an object?

This is the html

```
<nav class="nav">
    <a id=0> Test</a>
    <a id=1> Test</a> 
    <a id=2> Test</a>
</nav>
```

I thought of something like this:

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

I don't get it, why i get downvoted so much? ..

Comment: object!! what object?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to add an attribute to what? .nav element?

Comment: try putting ' "" ' <-- quotes on your ids

Comment: @roasted i want to and the attribute of the selected element to the object

Comment: @tmanolescu sorry, but really i still don't understand. What is the object you are talking about??? Give example

Comment: @roasted when you click on the element ex first anchor of the nav, the click function creates an object for the selected element and i wanted to add that object the attribute of the element. Jay helped me out. check out the answer, if you still can't understand i will put a jsfiddle :)

Comment: @tmanolescu That's ok, you should have used the more specific term: an other DOM element because in js, mostly everything is an object

Comment: @roasted ok, sorry i am new at this, still learning :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have to go with your question then i would suggest you this:

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
   var id = this.id;
   alert(id);
   $("#obj").attr('id', id);
});
```

here `#obj` is the object which is getting an id attribute set by this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try same but add value to it

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr("id","my_id");
});
```

Your script will retrieve the attribute and mine will add the attribute and better to use **On click** event like

```
$('.nav a').on('click',function(){
    $(this).attr("id","My_id");
});
```

Comment: is there any way to add an attribute of the clicked element to an object?

Comment: i gave example with id....and id also an attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$('a').on("click",function(){
$(this).attr("id","value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated attribute for this, called [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
$('.nav a').click(function(event){
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var testArray=new Array();
$('.nav a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  testArray.push($(this).attr("id"));
  alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on this code

```
<input type="button" id="121" value="Click me" onClick="dispAttribute(this.value);"/>
<script>
function dispAttribute(val){
alert(val);
}
</script>
```

You can also send

***dispAttribute(this.id);

dispAttribute(this.type);***

ans so on